# @XmlElements marked with @XmlJavaTypeAdapters?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb, jaxb2

I have this situation

```
@XmlType(name ="", propOrder={"value"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "compound")
public class Compound extends Value {
  @XmlElements({
  @XmlElement(name="simple", type=Simple.class),
  @XmlElement(name="compound", type=Compound.class)
  })
  protected List<Value> value;
  // ...
}
```

So a Compound is a List of both Simple and/or Compound. Both extend from Value that is defined as

```
public abstract class Value implements Serializable {}
```

Simple is a class marked with an adapter to marshal/unmarshal to/from a simple string

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SimpleAdapter.class)
public class Simple extends Value {
  private java.lang.String simple;
  // ...
}
```

Compound does not need an adapter.

The problem is that if I use a Simple 'as is', it correctly marshals/unmarshals as

```
<simple>my.text.here</simple>
```

but if I use it inside a Compound it outputs something like

```
<compound>
  //...
  <simple>
    <value>my.text.here</value>
  </simple>
  //...
</compound>
```

And I'm just wondering why... Do I miss something? How can i remove that 'value'?
It seems to me that the Adapter is not used at all, is it possible to use adapters in types marked inside @XmlElements?

**EDIT**

After few tests i found that the problem could be in how i handle a Simple instance. So I simplify my initial question in:

Given the a Simple class like

```
@XmlRootElement("simple")
public class Simple {
  private java.lang.String innerText;
  // getters/setters
}
```

how can i obtain a marshalled output like

```
<simple>
  my.inner.text.here
</simple>
```

instead of

```
<simple>
  <value>my.inner.text.here</value>
</simple>
```

?

Comment: A minor thing. You wrote both `Compound` and `Simple` inherit from `Value`, but that isn't reflected in their definitions.

Comment: Another thing. Are you sure the output if marshalled within `Compound` is `<simple><value>my.text.here</value></simple>` and not `<simple><simple>my.text.here</simple></simple>`? I would understand the latter, but I don't see why would the former happen. Where's the `value` element name defined?

Comment: All in all, it looks like you have far bigger model and you are manually extracting the most key things and posting it here. I am not sure if you run them. Maybe it would be great if you extracted a simple example (as you try), run it and share the whole context and outcome with us?

Comment: You are right, this is just an extract of a bigger generated (and much edited) schema that i'm not totally allowed to post. Anyway i'll try to make a simple testcase to show what i mean. I've edited the sample to fix inheritance, and no i don't know where that 'value' comes from.

Comment: The reason I posted these comments is tried something what I thought follows your description, but my results were different. And as usual these are the details which matter. I totally understand posting the whole model might be out of question, but even it was possible it wouldn't constitute a good example.

Comment: After few tests i simplified the question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want `private java.lang.String innerText;` to be the @XmlValue of your Simple class. Try to annotate the String in Simple with the @XmlValue tag:

```
@XmlRootElement("simple")
public class Simple {
  @XmlValue
  private java.lang.String innerText;
  //getters/setters
}
```

Or if you were using annotations on your getter method (which I assume based on your XML output in the question change your @XmlElement tag to a @XmlValue tag:

```
@XmlValue
public java.lang.String getInnerText() {
  return innerText;
}
```

When I do this I get the output you are looking for in your edited question.

Comment: Thank you, now the problem is another one... Simple class extends an abstract base class called Value. When i try to marshall it, i get something like **"The
property or field s can not be annotated with XmlValue since it is a subclass of another class"**. How con i solve this?

Comment: Ok, add `@XmlTransient` to the Value class. That should solve the problem.

Comment: @ciosbel did you try the `@XmlTransient` annotation on the `Value` class? It gave me the result you were looking for with the implementation I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer given by bamana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084895/xmlelements-marked-with-xmljavatypeadapters/6103442#6103442) is correct, however the exception you are seeing is due to a bug in the JAXB reference implementation.  This bug also existed in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) but has been fixed in the 2.3.0 stream, a nighty download can be obtained here:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

As a workaround you could use the XmlAdapter approach that was in your original question:

**SimpleAdapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class SimpleAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Simple> {

    @Override
    public Simple unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        Simple simple = new Simple();
        simple.setSimple(v);
        return simple;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Simple v) throws Exception {
        return v.getSimple();
    }

}
```

**Simple**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SimpleAdapter.class)
public class Simple extends Value {
    private java.lang.String simple;

    public java.lang.String getSimple() {
        return simple;
    }

    public void setSimple(java.lang.String simple) {
        this.simple = simple;
    }

}
```

**Compound**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "compound")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Compound extends Value {
    @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "simple", type = Simple.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "compound", type = Compound.class) })
    protected List<Value> value;

    public List<Value> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<Value> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**Value**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public abstract class Value implements Serializable {}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Compound.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Compound compound = (Compound) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(compound, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<compound>
    <simple>
        <simple>FOO</simple>
    </simple>
    <compound/>
</compound>
```

Comment: That was exactly my original idea, but i don't want a simple to be marshalled like your input file, without that inner <simple> wrapper.

Comment: @ciosbel - I believe the behaviour you are seeing is a bug, I am currently trying to fix this behaviour in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).  However if you do use MOXy you can just use the `@XmlValue` without the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` anyways.

Comment: @ciosbel - You can track the progress of this issue in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) via the following bug:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/347026

Comment: So this is a bug. Thank you. If it's painless I'll try to switch to the MOXy implementation and test the @XmlValue hint.